# kotlinx.coroutines not found

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing React Native and implemented a custom UI component for Android. One of the props I send to the component is a large array of objects. The deserialization in Android (Kotlin) tooks some time (>200ms) and I'm trying to use `async` to prevent blocking the UI.

```kotlin
@ReactProp(name = "items")
fun setItems(view: CustomListView, items: ReadableArray) {
    async {
        val itemsList = deserializItems(items)
        view.setItems(itemsList)
    }
}
```

but Android Studio says: `Unresolved reference: async`

I added these to my **app** `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"
```

and tried to import manually `kotlinx.coroutines` but Android Studio doesn't find it as well.

How can I get `async` functionality in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a coroutine scope to be able to call `async`.

I am not familiar with react development, but how i would use it something like this from inside a viewModel.

```
val asyncFunction = viewModelScope.async {
        //do your background work here
    }
```

and then you need to `await()` it later.

```
    viewModelScope.launch {
        asyncFunction.await()
    }
```

For import i have this in the gradle files

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
```

and these are the imports

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
```

Also, it might sound silly, but make sure to sync gradle after adding the dependencies.

[image: Gradle sync]

Or by using the "Sync Now" button displayed on the screen when editing the gradle file.

Comment: I can't even add the `import` statement...

Comment: I updated it with more info. Let me know if the rest of my answers helps.

Comment: Just published my own answer. Apparently I missed the "Syncing" (not silly at all for beginners :))

Comment: Oh, yeah , there is also the "sync now" button. I try to be careful when suggesting maybe obvious answers since some people can take it as an offense.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding coroutines dependency.

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).